# How Select SUBSTRING in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, select, substring

I need select a subtring to get the consecutive number from a table field.  My table is:

```
ORDER_NUM       ORDER_DATE   ORDER_TYPE  LOCATION   SALE_TYPE
10501702315618  08/01/17       43223       1050        18    
105017023186230 21/01/17       43221       1050        230
```

The field ORDER_NUM is generated as follows

```
[LOCATION] + [YY] + [CONSECUTIVE_NUMBER] + [SALE_TYPE]
```

The  length of the  fields LOCATION and SALE_TYPE Can be different.So, my query is:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTR(ORDER_NUM,LENGTH (ORDER_TYPE)  + 3,LENGTH (ORDER_NUM)   - LENGTH ( SALE_TYPE ) ),
ORDER_DATE
FROM 
CAT_ORDERS
WHERE 
LOCATION = '1050'
AND SALE_TYPE = '18'
```

The result is

```
    SELECT SUBSTR('10501702315618',7,12) from dual
    RESULT: 02315618
```

Where the index position is:

```
 12345678901234
 10501702315618
```

How i can delete the SALE_TYPE characters from the string? There is another function for this ?

Thank's!

Comment: Is CONSECUTIVE_NUMBER length fix or varying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description refers to the location, so it's odd that your offset is based on order type. The length of the substring needs to exclude the length of the location and the year as well:

```
SUBSTR(ORDER_NUM, LENGTH (LOCATION) + 3,
  LENGTH (ORDER_NUM) - LENGTH(LOCATION) - 2 - LENGTH (SALE_TYPE))
```

At the moment you're getting 12 characters from your offset, when you only want six, and there are only actually eight available.

Demo with your data:

```
WITH CAT_ORDERS (ORDER_NUN, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TYPE, LOCATION, SALE_TYPE) AS (
  SELECT 10501702315618, TO_DATE('08/01/17', 'DD/MM/RR'), 43223, 1050, 18 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 105017023186230, TO_DATE('21/01/17', 'DD/MM/RR'), 43221, 1050, 230 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT SUBSTR(ORDER_NUM, LENGTH (LOCATION) + 3,
  LENGTH (ORDER_NUM) - LENGTH(LOCATION) - 2 - LENGTH (SALE_TYPE))
FROM CAT_ORDERS;

023156
023186
```

---

**Your order number duplicates data from other columns, which doesn't seem ideal. It would be simpler to only store the 'consecutive number' part instead, and generate the full order number as a virtual column.**

Comment: I can't help myself... I would have just written the last paragraph and disregarded the rest. I'll go ahead and change it to boldface (please change it back if you disagree).  :-)

Comment: @mathguy - yeah, but then it would have been NAA *8-) I had it just as a comment to start with but could just about justify squeezing it into a broader answer...

Answer (score 2):

This should remove the sale_type characters from the end:

```
select 
  substr(substr(order_num, 0, length(order_num)-length(sale_type)), length(location) + 3)
from t;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select  regexp_substr(ORDER_NUM,'^' || LOCATION || '..(.*)' || SALE_TYPE || '$',1,1,'',1)
from    mytable;
```

---

Since we know now that the length of `consecutive_number` is fixed (namely, 6):

```
select  regexp_substr(ORDER_NUM,'^' || LOCATION || '..(.{6})',1,1,'',1)
from    mytable;
```

or

```
select  regexp_substr(ORDER_NUM,'(.{6})' || SALE_TYPE || '$',1,1,'',1)
from    mytable;
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone, all the answers work perfectly. @Dudu Markovitz, the consecutive number is fix (6). Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Since we know now that the length of `consecutive_number` is fixed (namely, 6):

```
select  substr(ORDER_NUM,length(LOCATION)+3,6)
from    mytable;
```

or

```
select  substr(ORDER_NUM,-length(SALE_TYPE)-6,6)
from    mytable;
```

Comment: In that case, it is really simple.

Comment: Have you checked it?